# How to create a new InArgument<T> where the T can be changed dynamically

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

In a rehost WorkflowDesigner, I want to assign a valiable to InArguments by following code:

```
 Type inActivityType = leftActivity.GetType();
 PropertyInfo inPropInfo = inActivityType.GetProperty(inArgumentName);
 InPropInfo.SetValue(leftActivity, 
                     new InArgument<someType>(new VisualBasicValue<someType>(variableName)), 
                     null);
```

Since the "someType" is assigned with different type dynamically, the regular way to create a new InArgument will not working. One idea I found is:

```
//  Type theType - the value of theType will be assigned dynamicly, 
//  base on different InArgument be selected

 Type InArgType = typeof(InArgument<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { theType });
 object InArg = Activator.CreateInstance(InArgType);
.  .  .
  InPropInfo.SetValue(leftActivity, 
                     InArg, 
                     null);
```

But the problem is, I can only create a new InArgument, but can not assign new VisualBasicValue(variableName) to it.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same trick to create a new instance of `VisualBasicValue`, too, and pass that along to `InArgument` using the [overload of `CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) that takes constructor arguments. Perhaps something like this:

```
Type InArgType = typeof(InArgument<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { theType });
Type vbValueType = typeof (VisualBasicValue<>).MakeGenericType(new[] {theType});
object vbValue = Activator.CreateInstance(vbValueType, variableName);
object InArg = Activator.CreateInstance(InArgType, vbValue);
```

However, depending on what you are tring to do, you could just use the non-generic [`InArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.inargument.aspx) instead and not worry about generics there.

Comment: Thanks a lot. On the last line of code, we also need pass vbValue as well, right?

Comment: +1 for dropping generics.  You blow away all benefits of generics by doing this.